# getting a regex expression to pass only if field is NULL/empty

Tags: regex, awk

i'm trying to work out with the code below how to pass a null value into the regex. so that should anything other than an empty area be found it prints the "invalid" code.

```
!($6~/^[]$/) {print "6th field invalid";
```

thanks for your help

Comment: An empty string regex is `/^$/`

Comment: Welcome to SO,you need to mention 3 simple things in your post always. 1st- sample of input, 2- sample of expected output, 3- what you have tried in CODE TAGS so that we could get a complete picture of your question. Kindly do so and do let us know then.

Comment: How about `$6!=""` or if you allow space in it `$6!~/^ *$/`?

Comment: thank you wiktor you've been a massive help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
awk '$6 != "" {print "invalid";}'
```

But you have to set the field separator properly. If it can match across an empty string (the default field separator is /[ \t]+/), $6 may be what you think is $7.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have NOT mentioned any samples so didn't check it, could you please try following.

```
awk '$6==""{print "6th field is empty"}'   Input_file
```

But again if you could mention samples of input in your post then it may help more to check this solution too.

Also in case you want to do vice-versa then try following as mentioned by @James Brown in comments too.

```
awk '$6!=""{print "6th field is NOT empty..etc.."}' Input_file
```

***NOTE:*** Since you have not shown us samples so you may need to set field separator for your Input_file, so please be aware of it too.